# ¿Cómo configurar el inicio de Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, configuración

Quisiera que `Android Studio` no me abriera el último proyecto al iniciar.
¿Alguien sabe donde se encuentra esa opción de configuración?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes deshabilitar la opción para que no abra el último proyecto al inicio de Android Studio.

Desde el menú ve a :

`File` > `Settings >Appearence & Behavior` > `System Settings`.

ahí deshabilita la opción :

**`Reopen last project on startup`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Cuando Android Studio esta abriendo el proyecto dale a Cancelar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego se te abrirá una nueva ventana con opciones, selecciona en esa ventana lo que quieras hacer.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para editar con que proyecto quieres iniciar:

> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings ->
>   Desmarca  "Reopen last project on startup" -> Aplicar

Comment: hola, si eso lo puedo hacer, pero me refería a si había la posibilidad de configurarlo para que aparezca esa pantalla de inicio

Comment: Pues intenta detallar más tú pregunta la próxima vez. 
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> desmarca "Reopen last project on startup" -> Aplicar

Comment: ok perdón y gracias por responder. Saludos

Comment: Nada para eso estamos, te lo digo para que no te pongan negativos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder y de hacer la corrección también, siempre se aprende algo.